# function to select user id and output selected data with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a function as below, but when I `echo $user_data['first_name'];` it pop out

> Undefined index: first_name.

can anyone help out?

```
$user_data = user_data($con, $user_id, $fields);

echo $user_data['first_name'];
// pop out error Undefined index: first_name.



function user_data($con, $user_id, $fields) {

    $data = array();
    $fields = implode(', ', $fields);
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT $fields FROM users WHERE user_id= $user_id");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    } 

    return $data;

} 

$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');

$fields = array('first_name', 'last_name','color');

$user_id = 1;

$data = user_data($con, $user_id, $fields);
```

Comment: You are not responding towards the answer.

Comment: Please educate yourself on SQL injection. Your code is vulnerable.

Comment: @BjörnTantau please feel free to comment my sql injection to educate me :)

Comment: Never ever use variables directly in SQL queries. It enables an attacker to control your database with his own queries. Always use prepared statements with value placeholders.

Comment: @BjörnTantau do u got any example i can look at it? thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @BjörnTantau thanks a lot, bro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $user_data[0]['first_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you will get data in array. So you need to traverse from other. Change your code like:

```
$user_data = user_data($con, $user_id, $fields);
foreach($user_data as $user){
  echo $user['first_name'];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The connection is created at the last line in the script given and after that only the database can be accessed so echo the result after using array traversal loops like Foreach,etc.
Add this line at the end of your script:

```
foreach($user_data as $user){
  echo $user['first_name'];  
}
```